# GraphQL custom filter directive

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I will make custom directive filter as instead of a resolver

but i'm having error Syntax Error: Expected Name, found @

schema

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server";
const typeDefs = gql`
 directive @where(columns: [String]) on ARGUMENT_DEFINITION | INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION
type Query {
 getUser(where: @where(columns: ["PersonColumn"])): String
}
type Mutation {
   updateUser(where: @where(columns: ["PersonColumn"])): String
}
`;
export default typeDefs;
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vYU4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the type of the field , before assigning schema-directives on that field
[image]

you need to this

```
insertUser(where: String! @where(columns["PersonColumn"])) : String
```